# How to optimize OR clauses in ON condition in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-optimization

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
  ON b.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN c
  ON c.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN (/* some complex subquery */) AS q
  ON q.id = a.id OR q.id = b.id OR q.id = c.id
```

Obviously it's not optimal because using ORs in the ON condition makes the planner unable to use indexes.

I tried to rewrite it like this:

```
WITH (/* some complex subquery */) AS q
SELECT a.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN q AS qa
  ON qa.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN b
  ON b.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN q AS qb
  ON qb.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c
  ON c.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN q AS qc
  ON qc.id = c.id
WHERE COALESCE(qa.id, qb.id, qc.id) IS NOT NULL
```

but it didn't get much faster because the database still needs to evaluate  the WHERE clause.

Is there any technique to optimize such a kind of joins? If not, then how can I redesign the schema?

Comment: This won't affect performance, but the `WHERE` clause is not needed because the original query uses a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: usually OR can be transformed to UNION

Comment: Got it! Thanks!